# How to call the content of a jsp into another portlet's jsp

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a requirement, i have to call a jsp which is available in another portlet project, i have to call the content of that jsp in another portlet's jsp.
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/66875852

Comment: Do you mean the processed content? or the unprocessed as in include?

Comment: Yes, i meant processed content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here its quite clear mentioned how to redirect from one portlet to another portlet jsps.
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/37527176

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what are you looking for:

```
<liferay-util:include page="/view.jsp" portletId="..." ></liferay-util:include>
```

Comment: you are right, but it will only display the string not the processed content.

Comment: Do you need to include the other portlet's jsp code into your plugin or include the rendered content into a String variable?

for the second one you can use
`<liferay-util:buffer var="otherPortletContentStr">
 <liferay-util:include page="/view.jsp" portletId="..." ></liferay-util:include>
</liferay-util:buffer>
<p>This is the content of the other portlet:
 <%= otherPortletContentStr %>
</p>`